# How to connect to a custom web domain created via OSX Server

Tags: macos, apache, osx-server

I switched from running Apache, which is built in the mac computer, to downloading the mac app OSX server. I am trying to host a custom website on that OSX server, but I can't connect to any of my html/php/ etc.. files even when i drop all the files I have been working on into the directory it tells me too.

It also says to connect you use localhost, but when i type in localhost i get this default screen from mac. The domain that i set up was www.uyswedding.com, i have tried

- localhost/www.uyswedding.com
- localhost/uyswedding

This very frustrating, and yes the web server is turned on. What is the correct syntax? Please anyone help.

Also it says the web files are stored in:

Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/www.uyswedding.com

how do I access those files in that dir??

Comment: You are using OS X Server in your question as if it has changed your computer into a server.  Your computer was already a Server, OS X Server just adds a massive amount of features to make lots of business related server features easier.  It's honestly a bit overkill for a simple website.  Which web framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just:

```
http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1
```

that should take you to any default webserver setup on port 80.  That is assuming you're trying to access the site via a browser running on the same machine.

Are you trying to access the website from another machine?  If so you'll need to find the IPaddress of the server machine.

Is this a completely new server machine or have you just changed the server software?  If it's a new machine, then you'll need to setup the IP address to be the same as the old machine so that your domain name routes to the server, etc.

Based on some research, try to add your content directories under:

```
/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default
```

which is one level deeper than you showed: /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/www.uyswedding.com, so move www.uyswedding.com under the Default directory.  Then you should be able to access via:

```
http://localhost/www.uyswedding.com
```

Comment: yes I just tried typing localhost, it just brings me to a default screen saying Welcome to OSX server. Before OSX server i set up apache server and used that to build my web site, I thought using OSX server would make things easier.. but i have not idea how to connect to it, and yes i am just using a local machine the same one I am running OSX server on.

Comment: Are you using Yosemite? If so I found the following: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083

Comment: I am using Yosemite, and yes is what I had to do to configure the Apache Server before I downloaded the OSX server. Ever since i downloaded that app from the mac store, it didn't overwrite any files or anything, but now localhost will only work if web server is turned on (in OSX server) and accessing localhost/~(short name)/index.html which used to work isn't working now

Comment: I edited the answer, try moving your custom directory under the Default directory and see if that works.  If not, you can always re-install Apache, and just leave the OSX Server config turned "off".